# How to leave some top gap for H2 title tag with css

Tags: html, css

In My Sidebar,i have a red colored background image for  H2 title.

I want the h2 title tag to be both vertically and horizontally centered.

I used `text-align: center;`. The result is this.

[image]

Its only horizontally centered and not vertically centered.
I added `vertical-align: middle;`,but it had no effect,I even tried `margin-top`,also it acted as if there was no such code

Lastly,I tried

```
 margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
```

Even that didnt work

The entire css

```
 #sidebar-wrapper h2 {
     background: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-FRYoELCr4cs/UWqPgG1XTjI/AAAAAAAAHZs/_825mjRMqrg/s295/54454554+copy.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
     color: rgb(213, 213, 213);
     height: 50px;
     width:294px;
     margin-top:10x;
     overflow: visible;
     position: relative;
     left: -16px;
     text-align: center;
     color:white;
     margin:0 0 10px
 }
```

If I alter the last line of margin,both the red colored background and title move(and not the title alone).Here is my [site.](https://www.blogger.com/blogin.g?blogspotURL=http://www.ilovetrolls.org/) Can someone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: This might be a good reading http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some padding to the style:

```
#sidebar-wrapper h2 {
     background: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-FRYoELCr4cs/UWqPgG1XTjI/AAAAAAAAHZs/_825mjRMqrg/s295/54454554+copy.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
     color: rgb(213, 213, 213);
     height: 50px;
     width:294px;
     margin-top: 10x; /* You have a typo here, is 10px */
     overflow: visible;
     position: relative;
     left: -16px;
     text-align: center;
     color:white;
     margin:0 0 10px
     padding: 7px 0; /* Magic padding */
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)
That typo took 1 hour of mine.
Initially when i had tried,padding moved the bg image as well....dont know why it works now...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use line-height.

```
#sidebar-wrapper h2 {
    background: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-FRYoELCr4cs/UWqPgG1XTjI/AAAAAAAAHZs/_825mjRMqrg/s295/54454554+copy.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: rgb(213, 213, 213);
    height: 50px;
    width:294px;
    margin-top:10x;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    left: -16px;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    margin:0 0 10px;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add this to your css:
     `padding-top: 7px;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use relative positioning. Try top: 10px.

Comment: This moves the bg image as well,i want to move only the text...anyways i found the ans below.Thanks a lot